# google geochart marker size and color

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

This is a two part question.

First, is there a way to change the size of the markers on google's Geochart when the points being plotted are only cities and don't have a population or size tied to them? I'm just listing cities with no value attached to it and all of Google's examples have some sort of population attached to it.

For example, Google uses this bit of code which the size of the marker is reflected by the population.

```
function drawMarkersMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City',  'Population', 'Area'],
    ['Rome',     2761477,    1285.31],
    ['Milan',    1324110,    181.76],
    ['Naples',   959574,     117.27],
    ['Turin',    907563,     130.17],
    ['Palermo',  655875,     158.9],
    ['Genoa',    607906,     243.60],
    ['Bologna',  380181,     140.7],
    ['Florence', 371282,     102.41]
  ]);
```

Is there any way to change the marker size without having it set by some sort of area or population?

Secondly, since I don't have a number for the marker size (only city name), how can I change the color of the markers? From what I understand, colorAxis is based off of the number tied to the city being plotted.

```
colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
```

Here's a link to the API's documentation https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Answer (score 2):

With some tweaking, you can do that.

Check out some examples I created:

http://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/svg-maps-of-the-states-in-usa/

To change the color, you should do something like this:

```
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Country'); 
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});

    data.addRows([[{v:"Olympia  Washington",f:"Olympia"},1,"Capital city of the state of Washington"],[{v:"Seattle Washington",f:"Seattle"},2,"Largest city of the state of Washington"],[{v:"Spokane  Washington",f:"Spokane"},3,"Seconde Largest city of the state of Washington"],[{v:"Vancouver  Washington",f:"Vancouver"},4,"Fourth largest city of the state of Washington"],]);

var options = {   colorAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:4,  colors: ['#4A9928','#204DA8','#992F1A','#2292C9',]},

    (...)
```

So, your incrementing a number, and giving as many different colors to match the values.

To change the size, I did not test it, but I guess a similar aproach would work, if you play around with this values:

```
sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:4,minSize:1,  maxSize: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the documentation you can't directly define the color and size of the markers in the Google Geochart. I would recommend you to try another solution for your task - [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/examples/markers-world/). When defining markers with `markers` parameter you can set the size and fill color for every marker or define default parameters using `markerDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Code for geo chart configuration option*/
$scope.geoChartConfig = function (data, regionName) {
  $scope.chart = {};
  $scope.chart.type = "GeoChart";
  $scope.chart.data = data

  $scope.chart.options = {
    // width: 800,
    // height: 500,
    resolution: 'provinces', //code to set city wise data 
    region: regionName,
    sizeAxis: {
      // minValue: 1, //code to set min and max values in geo chart
      // maxValue: 4,
      minSize: 4, //code to set min and max marker size
      maxSize: 4
    },
    // markerOpacity:1,//code to set opacity or transparancy of chart
    displayMode: 'auto', //auto, chart will automatically detect data set whether it is regions or points
    keepAspectRatio: true, // code to set max size of chart according to div size html
    backgroundColor: '#eaf9ff',
    datalessRegionColor: 'white',
    defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#1f77b4', '#55FF00', 'red'] //, '#ff0505'
    },
  };
}
```